# Project builds skipped with Any CPU build platform

Tags: visual-studio

All:

We are using Visual Studio 2010, and we have recently upgraded our workstations to Windows 7/64-bit.

I have a question:
When I create a new solution, it seems to want to use the x86 platform.  If I change the solution to "any cpu" and then I add a new project to the solution, the project will not have an "any cpu" build option, and it will be deselected from building (in configuration manager).

Something seems wrong here.  Here's what I want to have (assuming that it is supported):

I want my solutions' platforms to default to "Any CPU" (I believe that means that at JIT time, the assembly will be either x86 or 64-bit, based on the machine that loaded it).

When I add a new project to the solution, I want for it to have an "any cpu" solution, and I want for that projec to build by default.

(basically, the same behavior that we had in VS 2008 on 32-bit workstations).  How do I do that?  Is there some additional thing that I need to know now that I am using a 64-bit workstation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I think I have an answer now:
I read somewhere that if you are running VS on a 64-bit machine, and you are debugging 64-bit code, edit-and-continue is not supported.  I am surmising that in order to work around this, VS defaults to x86 mode instead of AnyCpu.

If anyone finds a better explanation, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: And BTW: has anyone had good luck with edit-and-continue? I had a lot of trouble with it not working when it was introduced in 2005, and I have been habitually turning it off ever since.  Ironically, I was thinking of turning it back on (we use VS 2010 now), but since we want to support AnyCpu deployment, I guess I'll just leave it off...

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I opened the project as administrator